# Use the Android gallery to display Media RSS

Tags: android, rss, media, gallery, android-contentprovider

I know that the native Gallery application of Android can display pictures stored from a Picasa Web account. I have searched the SDK but could not figure out if there is a way to make media rss available in the native gallery applications (and ideally would work with any gallery application).

I thought of creating a ContentProvider, to make these available but the gallery seems to only display what is added through the MediaStore.

If you have any idea, let me know.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add Media RSS in the native gallery without modifying its source code. No API allows that.